# Adding click event angularjs way without jquery

Tags: angularjs

How do i bind new event to DOM from controller in angular dynamically.

For html

```
<a href= "section" class="mdcl" />
```

say in jquery i will add click event

```
$(".mdcl").on('click',function(){
//Do something
});
```

How do i do the  same thing in angular js dynamically

usually we add in DOM which is straight forward

```
<a href= "section" class="mdcl" ng-click="functon()"/>
```

but if i don't have the control over DOM say content is coming from some where else and i need to add click event based on the class. how do i do this angular way?

Apologize if am repeating questions..i didn't come across similar question..

Thanks

Comment: how are you displaying HTML dynamically in your View ?

Comment: You can keep the same function and change your class dynamically using ng-class

Comment: @Rahul my content come via service and i inject it to my  partial view

Comment: if you have acces to the code of the service witch render the html .... yo can edit and add the ng-click directive before send.

Comment: @Vivz i dont have click event at all in the DOM..can i create click in controller?

Comment: @Peru so you can directly have `ng-click` in the content itself. just edit the content from where its coming. i.e. from server side

Comment: @JesusCarrasco if i have control i wouldnt have asked this quesition.am looking for way to do it

Comment: i think you can make an a directive in the parent element where you inject the partial html, and search for the elements you need to trigger the click event.

Comment: @Peru dont be rude, we are here to trying to help, we asking  to try how can you improve and resolve your question.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco sorry i did not mean to be  rude..but am trying to find how i can do this without adding ng-click in dom...some examples would help

Comment: @Peru you can go with the custom directive on parent element of your content. and add event handler for its child controller in directive same as of jQuery

Comment: thats was i  say above the comments, lol.

Comment: I didnt read though :D

Comment: `<div custom-directive>         link: function(attr, element){ element.querySelector('.mdl').click()}`try something like this.... try to attemp by your own and share the code and we try to help. Remember here is not coding service we need your code attemps to trying to help to resolve.

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, avoid doing DOM manipulation in controllers. DOM manipulation should be encapsulated in a custom directive. If a third-party library brings in DOM content from "somewhere else", that operation should itself be encapsulated in a [custom directive](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/docs/guide/directive) and events should be bound and connected to controllers with expression `'&"` binding attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.
It will be helpful for them who have constraints in writing code like dom should not be changed and only angularjs should be used.
Here is my answer

similar to jquery you can use `querySelecrtor` in angular like
in the controller you can write the following code

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('.mdcl')).bind('click' , function(){
//Do Something here
});
```

similarly you can bind the scroll event or any dom events in this way and you can use querySelector for selecting the DOM elements for example if you wan to select an id than a class you can replace `querySelector('#mdcl')`

here you can learn more about [angular element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, avoid doing DOM manipulation in controllers. DOM manipulation should be encapsulated in a custom directive. If a third-party library brings in DOM content from "somewhere else", that operation should itself be encapsulated in a [custom directive](https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/docs/guide/directive) and events should be bound and connected to controllers with expression `"&"` binding attributes.

Comment: yes i do know that but in the question he didnt explain the complete usage so i just said controller